# Seek bar and media player and a time of a track

Tags: android, media-player, seekbar

In my media player (mp3) there is a seek bar. To play the next song  i am using this logic:

> if (seek bar progress == mediaplayerObject.getDuration())

if yes 
play the next song

but this condition does not work, because there is a small mili second gap between the full seek bar progress and mediaplayerObject.getDuration() value that difference is not static it changes. I think it comes because of the processing time delays though. If I can use a condition like `if seek bar progress is 100%` I can use that, but I tried it does not seems working

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidMediaPlayerExample extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    public TextView songName, duration;
    private double timeElapsed = 0, finalTime = 0;
    private int forwardTime = 2000, backwardTime = 2000;
    private Handler durationHandler = new Handler();
    private SeekBar seekbar;
    private Field[] fields;
    private String name;
    private int resourceID;
    private List<String> songNames;
    private int nameIntRandom;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //set the layout of the Activity
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        songNames = new ArrayList();
        //initialize views
        initializeViews();



        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            //  seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());

                System.out.println("progress"+ (progress));
                System.out.println("progress final - "+ finalTime);

                if(progress == finalTime){
                    System.out.println("progress 100 compleated ");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }


    public void initializeViews(){
        listRaw();
        songName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songName);

        nameIntRandom = Integer.parseInt(songNames.get(2));


        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, nameIntRandom);
        finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();


        duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songDuration);
        seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        songName.setText("Sample_Song.mp3");

        seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
        seekbar.setClickable(false);
    }

    // play mp3 song
    public void play(View view) {
        System.out.println("AndroidMediaPlayerExample play");
        mediaPlayer.start();
        timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);
        durationHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBarTime, 100);
    }

    //handler to change seekBarTime
    private Runnable updateSeekBarTime = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //get current position
            timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            //set seekbar progress
            seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);
            //set time remaing
            double timeRemaining = finalTime - timeElapsed;
            duration.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) timeRemaining) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining))));

            //repeat yourself that again in 100 miliseconds
            durationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };

    // pause mp3 song
    public void pause(View view) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    // go forward at forwardTime seconds
    public void forward(View view) {
        //check if we can go forward at forwardTime seconds before song endes
        if ((timeElapsed + forwardTime) <= finalTime) {
            timeElapsed = timeElapsed + forwardTime;

            //seek to the exact second of the track
            mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) timeElapsed);
        }

    }

    public void listRaw() {

        fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
        for (int count = 0; count < fields.length; count++) {
            Log.i("Raw Asset: ", fields[count].getName());

            System.out.println("length .... " + fields[count].getName());

            try {
                System.out.println("trytrytrytry");
                resourceID = fields[count].getInt(fields[count]);
                System.out.println("resourceIDresourceID " + resourceID);
                name = String.valueOf(resourceID);
                songNames.add(name);
                System.out.println("songNames.size();" +songNames.size());
                songNames.size();

            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("catch" + e);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("resourceIDresourceID---------lastone " + resourceID);

        System.out.println("resourceIDresourceID---------set " + fields.toString());
    }


    // go backwards at backwardTime seconds
    public void rewind(View view) {
        //check if we can go back at backwardTime seconds after song starts
        if ((timeElapsed - backwardTime) > 0) {
            timeElapsed = timeElapsed - backwardTime;

            //seek to the exact second of the track
            mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) timeElapsed);
        }
    }

}
```

Currently mp3 arraylist id is hardcodeed

XML here

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#333333"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="songName" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mp3Image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
         android:padding="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/music"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_margin="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songDuration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="songDuration" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/media_rew"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:onClick="rewind"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_rew" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/media_pause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:onClick="pause"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/media_play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:onClick="play"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/media_ff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:onClick="forward"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I do not program in Java but is there not any delegate method you can call when the mp3 finishes playing ?

Comment: yes we have a one isPlaying() method but problem was where to use that

Comment: One way would be to access a property of the player, such as an `ActionAtItemEnd` property, which would automatically make the player advance (if you have a queue loaded in your player). Another way would be to add an observer on the song item which fires the delegate method at end time and does whatever else you want it to such as proceed to the next song

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, below i calculate timeElapsed ,set seekbar progress,calculate remaining time & display time already played in mins and seconds

I used this method

Ps : done this in 2015, no time to review code but explaining what i did.

**Runnable** -This interface is designed to provide a common protocol for objects that wish to execute code while they are active.Being active simply means that a thread has been started and has not yet been stopped.

**varibales** -

1. timeElapsed - time of the clip that already played
2. finalTime  - relevant media player clip object's time
3. duration -String that i used to display timeElapsed in minutes and seconds
4. timeRemaining - remaining time to play the clip

.

```
    private Runnable updateSeekBarTime = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                //get current position
                timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

                //set seekbar progress using time played
                seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);

                //set time remaining in minutes and seconds 
                timeRemaining = finalTime - timeElapsed;
                duration.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) timeRemaining) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining))));

                //holding time for 100 miliseconds
                durationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
            }
        };
```

so i can check `timeRemaining == 0`

and yes there is a method in media player 
`mediaPlayer.isPlaying()` <--- but i didnt use this